Uncaught (in promise) PrismaClientValidationError: Invalid client engine type
`been trying for the past few days to setup prisma on deno (Was enamoured by TS out of the box), so i set it all up and went on:
this is my schema:
datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = "file:./dev.db"
}

generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["deno"]
  output          = "../generated/client"
  engineType      = "binary"
}

model User {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  email        String @unique
  passwordHash String

  sessions         Session[]
  recievedMessages Message[] @relation("RecievedMessages")
  sentMessages     Message[] @relation("SentMessages")
}

model Session {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  ip        String
  userAgent String
  token     String @unique

  userId Int
  user   User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}

model Message {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  content String

  fromUserId Int
  fromUser   User @relation(fields: [fromUserId], references: [id], name: "RecievedMessages")
  toUserId   Int
  toUser     User @relation(fields: [toUserId], references: [id], name: "SentMessages")
}

this is the file where i reference prisma (prisma.ts):
import { PrismaClient } from "../generated/client/deno/edge.ts";

export const prisma = new PrismaClient();

these are the commands i use for prisma:
"tasks": {
    "migrate": "deno run -A --unstable npm:prisma migrate dev --name init",
    "generate": "deno run -A --unstable npm:prisma generate",
    "dev": "deno run -A --env-file --watch src/server.ts"
  },

and this is the error that pops up when running the "deno run dev"
error: Uncaught (in promise) PrismaClientValidationError: Invalid client engine type, please use `library` or `binary`
    at cs (file:// /server/generated/client/runtime/edge-esm.js:12:65)
    at new t (file:// /server/generated/client/runtime/edge-esm.js:29:3661)
    at file:// /server/db/prisma.ts:3:23

Tried a plethora of ways to fix this problem:

to generate the client in a different directory and in different ways
tried different ways to set up the schema
mess around with the node-modules folder and still didn't work
tried to change the import in the prisma.ts to the way the docs mentioned (@prisma/client)

